# why is there written Process terminated with status -1073741510 on my logs

Tags: c++

i was just trying code::blocks a few min ago and I just did a simple c out to see if it works

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "first program" << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

what`s wrong in this??

Comment: Nothing. Care to share the actual output you saw which made you wonder? Also, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: When copied & pasted into my compiler, it just runs fine... maybe you should check your environment.

Comment: BTW: You can use the search bar above. If you put in "[c++] status 1073741510" it gives you a few results already. Note that you should _not_ put the negative value you receive in there, because in the search, it means "exclude any results with 1073741510 in it".

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt if you want to search for `-` just put it in [quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+status+%22-1073741510%22) (same works on google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good habit to convert such negative output values from decimal to hexadecimal and to search online for information:

```
Decimal :     -1073741510
Hexadecimal : FFFF FFFF C000 013A
```

So, you can search for `"C000013A"`.

[This link](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/31733/what-means-exit-code-0xc000013a-during.html) mentions something might be wrong with the way you start/stop your program. I would advise you to launch a command prompt and to launch your program from there. Like this, you should not have that entry in your logs.